# How to fake keyboard event to widget in Qt5

Tags: qt5, keyboard-events

I have made a custom virtual keyboard widget for my kiosk application, and now comes the time when I want it to produce fake keyboard events and feed them to an QLineEdit of choice.

I do the following:

```
// target is the QWidget to receive the events
// k is the Qt::Key (keycode) I want to send (Testing with an 'A')
Qt::Key k=Qt::Key_A;
if(0!=target){
    //According to docs this will be freed once posted
    QKeyEvent * press=new QKeyEvent(QKeyEvent::KeyPress, (int )k,0);
    QKeyEvent * release=new QKeyEvent(QKeyEvent::KeyRelease, (int )k,0);
    //Give the target focus just to be sure it is available for input
    target->setFocus();
    //Post the events (queue up and let the target consume them when the eventloop gets around to the target)
    QCoreApplication::postEvent ( target, press) ;
    QCoreApplication::postEvent ( target, release) ;
}
```

I see the target widget receive focus, but there are no letters typed into the input field like I would expect. What am I doing wrong? Which assumptions are wrong?

PS: I know that this could be solved by using existing virtual keyboards or at least using the platform interface as is done in [this post](http://tolszak-dev.blogspot.no/2013/04/qplatforminputcontext-and-virtual.html). In our approach we have decided to build the kayboard into the application to obtain full control over the UX and keyboard design.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at Qt's [Virtual Keyboard](http://doc.qt.digia.com/QtVirtualKeyboard/index.html) framework?

Comment: And in general, I recommend reading this thread: http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-2463.html

Comment: Yes we have, however as I mentioned in the question, we are looking for a very tightly integrated solution. Our keyboard will be placed as a widget inside the app at specific locations, and will include specialized keys relevant for the specific feilds to be edited. We also need full control over when the keyboard should show up. I also think this question is relevant in its own right; how can one fake keyboard events in Qt5?

Comment: Thanks for the general comment! It was very useeful!

Comment: Did you read through the thread as well? Specifically, the data used by the various Qt widgets that deal with key-presses to produce text isn't the ``key`` value, it's the ``text`` value, which you are currently leaving blank. But the general consensus is that for a full-fledged virtual keyboard/mouse, you're much better off implementing a solution that actually integrates with the underlying OS mechanics (such as the VK framework) than trying to reinvent the wheel. You're not actually firing system-wide key-press events when you do what you're doing, and so expected behavior might not happen.

Comment: As a simple example, right now you have no simple way of properly implementing copy-paste functionality via keyboard shortcuts, if that's a concern for you (it may not be in a kiosk).

Comment: Actually copy/paste is a concern for us in that we would NOT want it to be available (we are making a kiosk application after all). For me, just making sure the text was provided worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no-one stepped up, I will try to provide some closure.

It turns out that Qt5 comes with a library of testing facilities called [testlib](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qttest-index.html). It has all sorts of goodies to facilitate easy creation, management and running of unit tests for Qt application. Among these facilities there is a set of functions for sending fake events such as fake typing of text, mouse clicks etc. It is quite comprehensive and covers many use-cases. Since this is used internally by Qt developers to test Qt itself it is also production proven code.

I simply copied what I needed from there.